# Tilix - read out list of set key-commands used by tiling terminal emulator for GNOME

Tags: configuration, gnome3, gnome-terminal, terminal-emulator, tilix

Is there a way to read out the key-commands used by the tiling terminal emulator [Tilix](https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/) from the command line as a list to stdout?

[image]

Comment: You could export it from dconf, the keybindings are stored at /com/gexperts/Tilix/keybindings/

Comment: @Gerald Thanks for this one! With `dconf list /com/gexperts/Tilix/keybindings/` this was the accepted answer :-) Though it seems I only get the commands I added manually, not the ones set by default.